# Azure Key Vault API Not accepting raw JSON body params

Tags: json, azure, post, azure-keyvault

I have to use raw json in my post query to Azure Key Vault. Which I've done like so:

`{ "grant_type":"client_credentials" }`

I get a 400 error complaining that the body does not have 'grant_type'

How can I get Azure Key Vault API to accept the raw json body?

The headers are in the attached image

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW6SX.jpg)

body in Postman:
[body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDSH8.jpg)

[using urlencoded in raw-JSON body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLg7j.jpg)

The endpoint is: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) which returns a temporary access token.

Microsoft has confirmed with me that this endpoint cannot accept raw-JSON so I'll have to find some other way for my implementation.

Comment: Maybe show your body in postman?  What is the content type set to in the body (raw or Json)?

Comment: body is: the same one that is in the OP { "grant_type":"client_credentials" }

in Postman it's set to raw with JSON selected from the drop down menu.

Updated the OP with a picture

Comment: I assume you're trying to get an access token first to be able to connect to KeyVault.  If so, I think there's more than just _'grant_type'_ required.  Take a look at this article from C# Corner which walks through connecting to Vault with Postman - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-access-azure-key-vault-secrets-through-rest-api-using-postman/

Comment: Yes grant_type is not the only required param. I'm not bothering to add other params until I know it's getting through. 

I know this request is not getting through because it complains the body does not have grant_type even though I've clearly added grant_type to the body. If it was getting through then it would complain about missing another param besides grant_type. 

If i use form-data I can get the access token just fine but for my implementation I need to use raw json.

Answer (score 0):

Your post data needs to be **URLEncoded**.  This can be done in Postman using a pre-request script. You can read the full walk-through on **Jon Gallant's** blog here: [Azure REST APIs with Postman](https://aka.ms/azurerestblog) or watch the video here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: thanks however that pre-request script sends the same post-request I'm trying to send and does it in x-www-form-urlencoded format. I can get the same result by switching Postman to x-www-form-urlencoded however that doesn't solve the problem. I tried changing the raw-JSON body to include urlencoded with no success. (See new picture in OP)

Comment: What API endpoint are you hitting?  I don't see that anywhere in your question.

Comment: trying to get the bearer token via secret key https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Microsoft has confirmed with me that this endpoint cannot accept raw-JSON body so I'll have to find some other way for my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint cannot read raw JSON.

The only solution is to modify the request body to use urlencoded format.

In Postman this can be done by changing the content type to: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and the body to *Raw* with the content inside the body as *&{key}={value}*  for every key, value that the endpoint requires.

Without access to the API sending the request I'm unfortunately unable to solve this issue since I'm forced to use JSON objects as the request body.